# Razor Page Large File Upload resulting in 400 Bad Request

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, razor, file-upload, razor-pages

I have a razor page for uploading files. I've set the maximum upload size to 4GB, but when I upload something larger than 2 GB I get an 400 Bad Request Error. I've added everything I found on the internet, that might help with the maximum upload size. At one point I thought the error was gone, but then it came back, with nothing changed in the code.
The Website is hosted on an IIS.

Has someone a hint what it might be? I'll include all upload size related code I've got.

**Sidenote: When I upload a file > 2GB but < 4GB i get an 400 Bad Request Error.
When I upload a file larger than 4GB I get an 413 Request Entity Too Large Error.**

I have these settings in my program.cs:

```
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.BufferBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.BufferBody = true;
    o.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
});

builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});

builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(c =>
{
    c.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
});
```

These settings in my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- ~ 2GB -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="419430412" executionTimeout="3600" /> // kbytes
    <globalization 
           requestEncoding="utf-8"
           responseEncoding="utf-8"
        />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- ~ 4GB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" /> // bytes
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And this is the upload code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 4294967295)]
    [RequestSizeLimit(4294967295)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var files = Request.Form.Files;

        // Für Progress Bar
        var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        var totalBytes = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

        //long bytesUploaded = 0;
        //var progressHandler = new ProgressHandler(_httpContextAccessor);

        // Folder Name 
        var folderName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss") + " - " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedResp");
        var folderPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\UploadTool\Uploads", folderName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

            if (files.Count == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No files selected.");
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, file.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }

        } 
        else
        {
            //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Folder already exists!");
        }

        return RedirectToPage("Upload");
    }
```

Comment: 400 error is the client has sent a request to IIS that breaks one or more rules that HTTP.sys is enforcing. you need to see what exactly the client is sending to IIS, To do it, capture a network trace of the client sending the bad request. You can analyze the trace to see the raw data that the client sends to IIS, and to see the raw response data that IIS sends back to the client. You can also use an HTTP sniffer tool called Fiddler, a great tool as it allows you to see the HTTP headers even if the client and server are communicating over SSL.

Comment: int.MaxValue is about 2GB.  Methinks you'd need something larger.  (you're setting number of bytes)  You might try Int64.MaxValue?    (though I think that would be 9223372036 GB??)  Maybe just set it to whatever your limit might be...  right now it's at 2147483647 bytes... (about 2.14GB?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the problem. Thanks to @pcalkins

```
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 4L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L;
    o.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.BufferBodyLengthLimit = 4L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L;
    o.BufferBody = true;
    o.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
});

builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = Int64.MaxValue;
});

builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = Int64.MaxValue;
});
```